# Java (J2SE) DTMF tone detection

Tags: java, java-io, at-command, dtmf

I am trying to do the following

- I am getting a call to another person using my java application (Already done & works fine).
- Then I am playing a recording, for example "Please press 1 one to continue in english" (Already done & works fine).
- Now I want to detect that person press one, As per my researches in google search I got that this can do using DTMF.If the person press 1 I want to do the actions according to my condition.

My question is how to detect that number using DTMF in java (J2SE). I am using ZTE USB dongle to make the call. Dialing, Hangup, And other controls did by using AT commands + Java IO.

Here is my example code, but it is not giving the correct dial number and its looping every time.

```
public class zxczczz extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form zxczczz
 */
public zxczczz() {
    initComponents();
}
float[] lowFreq = new float[]{697.0F, 770.0F, 852.0F, 941.0F};
float[] highFreq = new float[]{1209.0F, 1336.0F, 1477.0F, 1633.0F};
float[] dtmfTones = new float[]{697.0F, 770.0F, 852.0F, 941.0F, 1209.0F, 1336.0F, 1477.0F, 1633.0F};
int dtmfBoard[][] = {{1, 2, 3, 12}, {4, 5, 6, 13}, {7, 8, 9, 14}, {10, 0, 11, 15}};
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
static final char FRAME_SIZE = 160;
AudioFormat format = getAudioFormat();
int[] buf;
public boolean wait = false;
static boolean continueParsingDtmf = false;

public AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
    //  float sampleRate = 8000.0F;         
    float sampleRate = 44100.0F;
    //int sampleSizeInBits = 16;            
    int sampleSizeInBits = 8;
    int channels = 1;
    boolean signed = true;
    boolean bigEndian = true;

    return new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channels, signed, bigEndian);
}

public class DtmfCapture extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        continueParsingDtmf = true;
        try {

            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
            TargetDataLine out = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

            out.open(format);
            out.drain();
            out.start();
            int count = 0;

            while (continueParsingDtmf) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                //grab audio data
                count = out.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                if (count >= 0) {
                    zxczczz.DecodeDtmf dtmf = new zxczczz.DecodeDtmf(buffer);
                    if (!wait) {  

dtmf.start(); //look for dtmf
//  System.out.println("aaaaaa");
Thread.sleep(100);  
} else {  
Thread.sleep(1000);// wait before searching again
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
                        wait = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}  
public class DecodeDtmf extends Thread {

    byte[] buffer;

    DecodeDtmf(byte[] buffer) {
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    public void run() {
        int[] buf;

        buf = new int[buffer.length / 2];

        for (int j = 0; j < buffer.length / 2 - 1; j++) {
            buf[j] = (int) ((buffer[j * 2 + 1] & 0xFF) + (buffer[j * 2] << 8));
        }
        int tone = findDTMF(buf);

        if (tone >= 0) {
            wait = true;
            if (tone < 10) {
                System.out.println(" THE TONE IS : " + tone);
            }  

if (tone == 12) {
//                    System.out.println(" THE TONE IS :  A");
//                }
//                if (tone == 13) {
//                    System.out.println(" THE TONE IS : B");
//                }
//                if (tone == 14) {
//                    System.out.println(" THE TONE IS : C");
//                }
//                if (tone == 15) {
//                    System.out.println(" THE TONE IS : D");
//                }
            if (tone == 10) {
                //      System.out.println(" THE TONE IS : *");
            }
            if (tone == 11) {
                //      System.out.println(" THE TONE IS : #");
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     Check if sample has dtmf tone
     */
    public int findDTMF(int[] samples) {
        double[] goertzelValues = new double[8];
        double lowFreqValue = 0;
        int lowFreq = 0;
        double sumLow = 0;
        double highFreqValue = 0;
        int highFreq = 0;
        double sumHigh = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            goertzelValues[i] = goertzel(samples, dtmfTones[i]);
        }
        // System.out.println("aa="+goertzelValues);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) // Find st?rste low frequency
        {
            sumLow += goertzelValues[i]; // Sum til signal-test
            if (goertzelValues[i] > lowFreqValue) {
                lowFreqValue = goertzelValues[i];
                lowFreq = i;
            }
            //      System.out.println("low = "+i);
        }
        for (int i = 4; i < 8; i++) // Find st?rste high frequency
        {
            sumHigh += goertzelValues[i]; // Sum til signal-test
            if (goertzelValues[i] > highFreqValue) {
                highFreqValue = goertzelValues[i];
                highFreq = i - 4;
            }
        }
        if (lowFreqValue < sumLow / 2 || highFreqValue < sumHigh / 2) // Test signalstyrke
        {
            return -1;
        }
        // System.out.println("aaa="+dtmfBoard[lowFreq][highFreq]);
        return dtmfBoard[lowFreq][highFreq]; // Returner DTMF tone
    }
}

public double goertzel(int[] samples, float freq) {
    double vkn = 0;
    double vkn1 = 0;
    double vkn2 = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < samples.length - 1; j++) {
        vkn2 = vkn1;
        vkn1 = vkn;
        vkn = 2 * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * (freq * samples.length / format.getSampleRate()) / samples.length) * vkn1 - vkn2 + samples[j];
    }
    double WNk = Math.exp(-2 * Math.PI * (freq * samples.length / format.getSampleRate()) / samples.length);
    //System.out.println(WNk);
    return Math.abs(vkn - WNk * vkn1);

}  
}
```

Please Help me.

Comment: Is there anyone to give me a backup support?

Comment: I think if we can solve this it may be help to many of coders to develop something like this.All advices,sample codes are warmly welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

i was looking for the same thing for DTMF Detection in ActionScript
i found something maybe you can recode this in java

```
  package {
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class DTMFprocessor
    {

        /*
           The following constants are used to find the DTMF tones.  The COL1 is the column Hz that we
           are searching for, and the COL2 is the row Hz.  The DTMF_LAYOUT is the order that the cols and
           rows intersect at.
        */

        private static const COL1:Array = [697, 770, 852, 941];
        private static const COL2:Array = [1209, 1336, 1477, 1633];
        private static const DTMF_LAYOUT:Array = [ ["1","2","3","A"] ,
                                                   ["4","5","6","B"] ,
                                                   ["7","8","9","C"] ,
                                                   ["*","0","#","D"] ];

        private var sampleRate:int;
        private var lastFound:String = "";

        public var DTMFToneSensitivity:int = 15;

        /**
         * DTMF Processor Constructor
         * 
         * @param sampleRate  This is the sample rate, in frames per second that the application is operating in.
         * 
         */     
        public function DTMFprocessor(sampleRate:int = 44100)
        {
            this.sampleRate = sampleRate;
        }

        /**
         * Generates DTMF byteArrays that can be played by the Sound() object.
         *  
         * @param length  length, in ms that the tone will be generated for.
         * @param tone    the string representing the tone that will be generated [0-9, A-D, *, #]
         * @return        the byteArray that contains the DTMF tone.
         * 
         */     
        public function generateDTMF(length:int, tone:String):ByteArray
        {
            var mySound:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            var neededSamples:int = Math.floor(length * sampleRate / 1000);
            var mySampleCol:Number = 0;
            var mySampleRow:Number = 0;

            var hz:Object = findDTMF(tone.charAt(0));

            for (var i:int = 0; i < neededSamples; i++)
            {
                mySampleCol = Math.sin(i * hz.col * Math.PI * 2 / sampleRate) * 0.5;
                mySampleRow = Math.sin(i * hz.row * Math.PI * 2 / sampleRate) * 0.5;
                mySound.writeFloat(mySampleRow + mySampleCol);

            }
            return mySound;
        }

        /**
         * Searches a ByteArray (from a Sound() object) for a valid DTMF tone.  
         *  
         * @param tone  ByteArray that should contain a valid DTMF tone.
         * @return      string representation of DTMF tones.  Will return a blank string ('') if nothing is found
         * 
         */     
        public function searchDTMF(tone:ByteArray):String
        {
            var position:int = 0;
            var charFound:String = "";

            // seed blank values for strongest tone to be found in the byteArray 
            var maxCol:int = -1;
            var maxColValue:int = 0;
            var maxRow:int = -1;
            var maxRowValue:int = 0;
            var foundTones:String = "";

            // reset the byteArray to the beginning, should we have gotten it in any other state.
            tone.position = position;

            // break up the byteArray in manageable chunks of 8192 bytes.  
            for (var bufferLoop:int =0; bufferLoop < tone.bytesAvailable; bufferLoop =+ 8192)
            {
                position = bufferLoop;

                // search for the column tone.
                for (var col:int = 0; col < 4; col++)
                {
                    if (powerDB(goertzel(tone,8192,COL1[col],position)) > maxColValue)
                    {
                        maxColValue = powerDB(goertzel(tone,8192,COL1[col],position));
                        maxCol = col;
                    }
                }

                // search for the row tone.
                for (var row:int = 0; row < 4; row++)
                {
                    if (powerDB(goertzel(tone,8192,COL2[row],position)) > maxRowValue)
                    {
                        maxRowValue = powerDB(goertzel(tone,8192,COL2[row],position));
                        maxRow = row;
                    }
                }

                // was there enough strength in both the column and row to be valid?
                if ((maxColValue < DTMFToneSensitivity) || (maxRowValue < DTMFToneSensitivity))
                {
                    charFound = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    charFound = DTMF_LAYOUT[maxCol][maxRow];
                }

                if (lastFound != charFound)
                {
                    trace("Found DTMF Tone:",charFound);
                    lastFound = charFound;  // this is so we don't have duplicates.
                    foundTones = foundTones + lastFound;
                }

            }
            return foundTones;
        }

        /**
         * Converts amplitude to dB (power).  
         *  
         * @param value  amplitude value
         * @return       dB
         * 
         */     
        private function powerDB(value:Number):Number
        {
            return 20 * Math.log(Math.abs(value))*Math.LOG10E;
        }

        /**
         * This function returns the amplitude of the a seeked wave in the buffer.
         *  
         * @param buffer      the byteArray that is being searched.
         * @param bufferSize  the size of the buffer that we wish to search.
         * @param frequency   the frequency (in Hz) that we are searching for.
         * @param bufferPos   the starting point that we want to search from.
         * @return            amplitude of the searched frequency, if any.
         * 
         */     
        private function goertzel(buffer:ByteArray, bufferSize:int, frequency:int, bufferPos:int):Number
        {
            var skn:Number = 0;
            var skn1:Number = 0;
            var skn2:Number = 0;

            buffer.position = bufferPos;

            for (var i:int=0; i < bufferSize; i++)
            {
                skn2 = skn1;
                skn1 = skn;
                if (buffer.bytesAvailable > 0)
                skn = 2 * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * frequency / sampleRate) * skn1 - skn2 + buffer.readFloat();
            }

            var wnk:Number = Math.exp(-2 * Math.PI * frequency / sampleRate);

            return (skn - wnk * skn1);
        }

        /**
         * Returns the Hz of the string tone that is searched.
         *  
         * @param tone  character that is being search for
         * @return      an untyped object that has col and row properties that contain the Hz of the DTMF tone.
         * 
         */     
        private function findDTMF(tone:String):Object
        {
            var myDTMF:Object = new Object();   

            switch(tone)
            {
                case "1":
                    myDTMF.col = COL1[0];
                    myDTMF.row = COL2[0];
                    break;
                case "2":
                    myDTMF.col = COL1[0];
                    myDTMF.row = COL2[1];
                    break;
                case "3":
                    myDTMF.col = COL1[0];
                    myDTMF.row = COL2[2];
                    break;
                case "A":
                    myDTMF.col = COL1[0];
                    myDTMF.row = COL2[3];
                    break;
                case "4":
                    myDTMF.col = COL1[1];
                    myDTMF.row = COL2[0];
                    break;
                case "5":
                    myDTMF.col = COL1[1];
                    myDTMF.row = COL2[1];
                    break;
                case "6":
                    myDTMF.col = COL1[1];
                    myDTMF.row = COL2[2];
                    break;
                case "B":
                    myDTMF.col = COL1[1];
                    myDTMF.row = COL2[3];
                    break;
                case "7":
                    myDTMF.col = COL1[2];
                    myDTMF.row = COL2[0];
                    break;
                case "8":
                    myDTMF.col = COL1[2];
                    myDTMF.row = COL2[1];
                    break;
                case "9":
                    myDTMF.col = COL1[2];
                    myDTMF.row = COL2[2];
                    break;
                case "C":
                    myDTMF.col = COL1[2];
                    myDTMF.row = COL2[3];
                    break;  
                case "*":
                    myDTMF.col = COL1[3];
                    myDTMF.row = COL2[0];
                    break;
                case "0":
                    myDTMF.col = COL1[3];
                    myDTMF.row = COL2[1];
                    break;
                case "#":
                    myDTMF.col = COL1[3];
                    myDTMF.row = COL2[2];
                    break;
                case "D":
                    myDTMF.col = COL1[3];
                    myDTMF.row = COL2[2];
                    break;              
                default:
                    myDTMF.col = 0;
                    myDTMF.row = 0;
            }
            return myDTMF;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Correction:

`case "D" :  
myDTMF.col = COL1[3];  
myDTMF.row = COL2[3];`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know enough to help you out, but have you seen the DTMF implentation in [TarsosDSP](https://0110.be/posts/Dual-Tone_Multi-Frequency_%2528DTMF%2529_Decoding_with_the_Goertzel_Algorithm_in_Java) on github?